# Android https post with hard coded URL and post data in Json format

Tags: android, kotlin

Apollogies for a question that I can see has alot of hits however I can't find any recent answers. Given how fast android dev moves I thought I would ask a new question.

New to kotlin and android dev, one off app.

Using Android Studio & Kotlin - How to make an app that executes a HTTPS POST with hard coded URL and POST data in JSON format once the app is opened. No user action required other than opening the app. The app needs no UI.

Comment: use the Executor-https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor#:~:text=An%20object%20that%20executes%20submitted,instead%20of%20explicitly%20creating%20threads.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the executor direction, I will see what I can do with it. If you have a code example inline with my question that would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I was looking for in ktor: https://ktor.io/docs/request.html#body

```
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.client.statement.*
import io.ktor.http.*

val response: HttpResponse = client.post("http://localhost:8080/post") {
    setBody("Body content")
}

val response: HttpResponse = client.post("http://localhost:8080/customer") {
    contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
    setBody(Customer(3, "Jet", "Brains"))
}
```